# Blazor can't find referenced component from other folder

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm trying out Blazor WebAssembly, and wanted to create some new components on top of the pregenerated example project from Visual Studio.

So, essentially what I ended up is the following folder structure:

```
Project
\ Components
  \ Navigation
    \ BurgerMenu.razor
      BurgerMenu.razor.css
      BurgerMenu.razor.less
\ Shared
  \ MainLayout.razor
    MainLayout.razor.css
    MainLayout.razor.less
```

So far so good. Here are my components:

MainLayout.razor:

```
@using Components.Navigation;

@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="sidebar">
    <BurgerMenu />
</div>

<div class="LayoutContainer">
    @Body
</div>
```

BurgerMenu.razor:

```
<div>
    Test Component
</div>

@code
{
}
```

As you can see, as of yet there is really nothing to write home about.

However, I can't get this to work properly. Every build complains regarding `warning RZ10012: Found markup element with unexpected name 'BurgerMenu'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.`

So, I'm a bit lost now. Accoding to the official docs, the @using statement should be the proper way to import the component from a folder - Which is there. However, this still doesn't work.

If I move the BurgerMenu.razor within the /Shared folder, everything works fine.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `@using` might need to be fully qualified (I'm assuming it's missing the name of the project before "Components"). Also, what does your _Imports file look like?

Comment: I had the same issue and restarting VS community edition solved it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd have thought the using statement would need to include your project name:

```
@using Project.Components.Navigation;
```

If I try something similar to you the editor underlines the using statement (without the project name) in red.

Answer (score 17):

This problem was fixed for my after restarting Visual Studio for me. I'm running Professional 2019 and apparently the intellesense gets stuck.

Comment: Just a head's up-- the project will still compile and run.  So if you suspect the same thing is happening, just ignore it.

Comment: it happened to me too

Comment: Same.  I'm using Visual Studio Community Edition and it's definitely not too good for Blazor.

Comment: @dam do you know of any alternative IDE for Blazor? Do you know if Visual Studio Professional has better support? How is support in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I've been told that JetBrains Rider is decent for Blazor work.  Try the community edition of that and see if you can debug.  VsCode has extensions and you can try to configure things to get debugging working but expect flakiness.  Visual Studio Enterprise Edition is what I expect should work the best but don't have a license so I can't tell you.

Answer (score 1):

I called my component UploadBlob and got green squiggly lines.  When I changed the name to UploadBlobComponent the name turned the right colour and all is well.